# ¿Cómo permitir que el wp-admin se ejecute desde un iframe?

Tags: wordpress

En un sitio web se utiliza godaddy para la gestión de su dominio, pero no para el hosting.

Entonces, si quiero acceder a la página con mi hosting, sería:

```
midominio.com/empresacliente
```

Creé una redirección enmascarada con un subdominio, tipo:

```
proyecto.empresacliente.com
```

Y hasta allí perfecto, sin embargo cuando intento usar lo mismo para el administrador:

```
midominio.com/empresacliente/wp-admin
```

En el godaddy lo asigno:

```
admin.empresaciente.com
```

Pero no funciona, la página se cae y por motivos administrativos, una redirección no basta.

Revisando el código de godaddy para el enmascaramiento, veo que usan un `iframe` para simular que la página está siendo cargada con ese dominio, creo que ahí radica el problema, pero no estoy seguro ¿Qué puedo hacer?